# Exception in Reducer in Hadoop when run on Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a map reduce program that runs perfectly when run in stand-alone mode but when I run it on Hadoop Cluster at my school, an exception is happening in the Reducer. I have no clue what exception it is. I came to know this as when I keep a try/catch in reducer, the job passes but empty output. When I don't keep the try/catch, job fails. Since it is a school cluster, I do not have access to any of the job trackers or other files. All I can find is through programatically only. Is there a way I can find what exception happened on hadoop during run time ?

Following are snippets of my code

```
public static class RowMPreMap extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text keyText = new Text();
    private Text valText = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        // Input: (lineNo, lineContent)

        // Split each line using seperator based on the dataset.
        String line[] = null;

        line = value.toString().split(Settings.INPUT_SEPERATOR);

        keyText.set(line[0]);
        valText.set(line[1] + "," + line[2]);

        // Output: (userid, "movieid,rating")
        output.collect(keyText, valText);
    }
}

public static class RowMPreReduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text valText = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        // Input: (userid, List<movieid, rating>)

        float sum = 0.0F;
        int totalRatingCount = 0;

        ArrayList<String> movieID = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Float> rating = new ArrayList<Float>();

        while (values.hasNext()) {
            String[] movieRatingPair = values.next().toString().split(",");
            movieID.add(movieRatingPair[0]);
            Float parseRating = Float.parseFloat(movieRatingPair[1]);
            rating.add(parseRating);

            sum += parseRating;
            totalRatingCount++;
        }

        float average = ((float) sum) / totalRatingCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < movieID.size(); i++) {
            valText.set("M " + key.toString() + " " + movieID.get(i) + " "
                    + (rating.get(i) - average));
            output.collect(null, valText);
        }

        // Output: (null, <M userid, movieid, normalizedrating>)
    }
}
```

Exception happens in the above reducer. Below is the config

```
public void normalizeM() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(UVDriver.class);
    conf1.setMapperClass(RowMPreMap.class);
    conf1.setReducerClass(RowMPreReduce.class);
    conf1.setJarByClass(UVDriver.class);

    conf1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf1.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf1.setKeepFailedTaskFiles(true);

    conf1.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf1.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf1, new Path(Settings.INPUT_PATH));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf1, new Path(Settings.TEMP_PATH + "/"
            + Settings.NORMALIZE_DATA_PATH_TEMP));

    JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(UVDriver.class);
    conf2.setMapperClass(ColMPreMap.class);
    conf2.setReducerClass(ColMPreReduce.class);
    conf2.setJarByClass(UVDriver.class);

    conf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf2, new Path(Settings.TEMP_PATH + "/"
            + Settings.NORMALIZE_DATA_PATH_TEMP));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(Settings.TEMP_PATH + "/"
            + Settings.NORMALIZE_DATA_PATH));

    Job job1 = new Job(conf1);
    Job job2 = new Job(conf2);

    JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("jobControl");
    jobControl.addJob(job1);
    jobControl.addJob(job2);
    job2.addDependingJob(job1);
    handleRun(jobControl);

}
```

Comment: Do you have access to port :8808 ? You can monitor job status and view stack trace etc from http://<hadoop-namenode-ip>:8088

Comment: @Anupam, I do not have any access to ports or trackers or anything else other than executing my program.

Answer (score 1):

I caught the exception in reducer and write the stack trace to a file in the file system. I know this is the dirtiest possible way of doing this, but I have no option at this point. Following is the code if it helps any one in future. Put the code in catch block.

```
                String valueString = "";
                while (values.hasNext()) {
                    valueString += values.next().toString();
                }

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();

                Path pt = new Path("errorfile");
                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(pt,true)));
                br.write(exceptionAsString + "\nkey: " + key.toString() + "\nvalues: " + valueString);
                br.close();
```

Inputs to do this in a clean way are welcome.

On a sider note, Eventually I found it is a NumberFormatException. Counters would not have helped me identify this. Later I realized the format of splitting input in stand-alone and on cluster is happening in different fashion, which I am yet to find the reason.

Comment: I put a try catch block around my reducer and mapper logic, too, but instead of just logging the exception I also increment the counter for group "Exception" and counter name e.getClass().getPackage()+"."+e.getClass().getName().  In other words, I use the counters to report back to the driver class (per my answer) how many errors there were of each kind.  That's really helped me tell at a glance what, if anything, went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't have access to the server, you can get the counters for a job:

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
```

and dump the set of counters to your local console.  These counters will show, among other things, the counts for the number of records input to and written from the mappers and reducers.  The counters that have value zero indicate the problem location in your workflow.  You can instrument your own counters to help debug/monitor the flow.